# Query using three terms in SQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using WordPress, but this question is more pertaining to the SQL involved. I'll gladly move it if I need to.

I'm working on http://www.libertyguide.com/jobs and I'm trying to alter the filtering mechanics.  Currently it's a global `OR` query.

Anyways, I have three filtering lists, and I'm storing what's selected into three strings (interests, type, experience) in the following way:

```
"( $wpdb->terms.slug = 'webdevelopment' OR $wpdb->terms.slug = 'journalism' OR ... ) AND"
```

It's populated by whatever is selected in my filtering lists.

When it comes down to it, I have this as a basic query (I'm leaving out the `LEFT JOINS`):

Before:

```
SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ($wpdb->terms.slug = 'fromlist1' 
OR $wpdb->terms.slug = 'fromlist2' OR $wpdb->terms.slug = 'fromlist3') 
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'jobtype'...
```

After:

```
SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE 
($wpdb->terms.slug = 'fromlist1' OR $wpdb->terms.slug = 'fromlist1again') 
AND ($wpdb->terms.slug = 'fromlist2' OR $wpdb->terms.slug = 'fromlist2again') 
AND ($wpdb->terms.slug = 'fromlist3' OR $wpdb->terms.slug = 'fromlist3again') 
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'jobtype'...
```

So essentially I want to go from an

`OR` filter

**to**

an `AND` filter with `OR` filtering inbetween.

My new filtering only works when one item overall is selected, but returns nothing when I select more than one thing (that I know would match up with a few posts).

I've thought through the logic and I don't see anything wrong with it.  I know nothing is wrong with anything else, so it has to be the query itself.

Any step in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE**
From the confusion, basically I have this:

```
"SELECT ...... WHERE $terms ..."
```

but I WANT

```
"SELECT ....... WHERE $interests AND $type AND $experience"
```

I don't want to have it filter `$interest[1] OR $interest[2] OR $type[1] OR $experience[1]`, but instead want it to filter `($interest[1] OR $interest[2]) AND ($type[1]) AND ($experience[1])`

I hope this makes more sense

****UPDATE 2****

Here's and example:

In my interests list, I select for example three things: WebDevelopment, Academia, Journalism.

In my type list, I choose two things: Fulltime, Parttime

In my experience list, I choose three things: Earlycareer, Midcareer, Latecareer.

When I run my query, I want to make sure that each record has AT LEAST one of each of the three lists.  Possible Results: (WebDevelopment, Parttime, Midcareer), (Academia, Fulltime, Earlycareer, Midcareer).

NOT A RESULT: (Journalism, Earlycareer) - missing fulltime or parttime

I really hope this clears it up more.  I'm willing to give compensation if I can get this working correctly.

Comment: Maybe this will help, as there is a lot of `WP` syntax that I know is throwing me off and might be throwing others off.  Can you give a sample list of `$interest[1`, `$interest[2]`, `$type[1]`, `$experience[1]` and then show which rows you are expecting/wanting the modified query to return?  As far as I can tell, you're saying it has to show up in both  `experience` and `type` and at least 1 of the `interest` lists, is that right?  If so, is the issue with making WP do it?

Comment: @Anthony I think you got it.  It's not just WP that I'm having problems with, it's the SQL statement.  Look out for an update with a sample list.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I'll take a shot at this:

```
SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE
(
$wpdb->terms.slug IN ('$interest1', '$interest2') AND 
$wpdb->terms.slug IN ('$type1', '$type2') AND 
$wpdb->terms.slug IN ('$exp1', '$exp2')
)
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'jobtype'
```

The `IN` keyword will return true if any member of the set matches.

Comment: I'm altering my code right now.  I'll post back if I find any issues.  Thank you SO much for your patience and your help!

Comment: Not a problem. It's pretty close to what you already had, so for sure let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Bummer.  Do you want to take this to a chat and hash it out?

Comment: That would be fantastic! Where would you like to chat?

Comment: I don't think I'll have the time to chat, but I have a pastebin of my current code that's relevant: http://pastebin.com/wEbqRYxq Thanks for the help :/

Comment: Sorry, gotta run to a dr. appt. I'll take a look when I get back. Good luck until then.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a `WHERE category IN (comma, seperated, list, of, values)` that you can generate dynamically from the form. If you combine it with the other categories, you can require them to select something from each with...

```
 WHERE category1 IN (a, comma, seperated, list, of, values)
 AND   category2 IN (another, list, of, values)
 AND ...
```

Which will only return a value if there is something selected from each category and will return nothing if any of the selection lists are empty; actually it may well kick out an error, so I would also generate the query dynamically if there is any content whatsoever for a given category.

```
if (!empty($arrayOfCategory1)) {  
    //sanitize input logic here  
    $Category[1] = 'category1 IN ('. implode(', ', $arrayOfCategory1) .')';  
} else {  
    $Category[1] = '';  
}
```

You concatenate the resultant string together and build the query with that. The `WHERE 1=1` trick is problematic because if nothing is chosen, everything in the database will match, so I strongly recommend going through the process of adding the `AND` operators properly.

EDIT: it occurs to me that if you build the conditional statements as an array, you can implode *those* with `' AND '` and get the query in a fairly small number of lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I never used the 1=1 trick and didn't plan on it (It will already return all posts of the cpt I need).  I didn't even think of the implode feature (I used a foreach and lopped off the final comma).  I'll keep your ideas in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sort of confused a bit by what you are saying but if I wanted to build a filter I would be dynamically generating the SQL query based on the submitted filter values. Something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE 1=1";
if ( !empty($interest) ) { // they ticked the interested in ??? checkbox
    $sql .= " AND $wpdb->terms.slug = $interest"
}
```

Obviously you will need to filter and escape any values that have been submitted.

Comment: I have that being generated already, I just spelled it out because that's essentially what it creates if something is selected. basically, Instead of filtering based on ALL of them selected using OR statements, I want to have it split up into the three different categories using AND filtering between them.

Comment: So you want to make sure that they select one from each $fromlist?

Comment: @Malovich Kind of. They don't NEED to select something from each, but I want it to filter based kind of on what they've previously selected in the filtering.  If you look at the website I posted, you should get the gist of what I mean. For example, If I choose Web Development AND Full-time, it will return posts with Web Development OR full-time, rather than a post with Web Development AND full-time. I can change the whole thing to an AND filter, but that doesn't solve for if somebody chooses more than one interest.

Comment: @JoshAllen - So you want the filter results to be those that definitely show up in both the `interest` and `type` list in addition to possibly showing up in the original 2?  If they have to show up in both of the last groups, will you actually get any further results from the first two groups?

Comment: @Anthony I won't get any further results, just more specific results. I want the results to have at least one of the selected `interests`, one of the selected `types`, and one of the selected `experiences`. So if I choose (WebDev,Journalism)(fulltime,parttime)(earlycareer,midcareer), I want the results to match up to AT LEAST (WebDev OR Journalism) AND (fulltime OR parttime) AND (earlycareer OR midcareer).  And that logic is exactly what I have, but it's not working.

Comment: @JoshAllen - In your first example, where the query is written almost fully out, you have : ` $wpdb->terms.slug = 'fromlist1' OR $wpdb->terms.slug = 'fromlist1again'`.  Is this the same as `interest[1]` and `interest[2]`?